# BuildWarner plugin doesn't work in incremental analysis - SonarQube 5.1

Tags: sonarqube

When I run an incremental analysis on my project through maven, [build warner plugin](https://github.com/NitorCreations/sonar-build-warner-plugin) is not called, resulting in an analysis completing successfully even if there are violations.

I have quality gate setup correctly (0 violations) and I have tried configuring sonar `sonar.preview.includePlugins` with `buildwarner` plugin in General settings, but without luck - the plugin is still not called in an incremental analysis.

The plugin works correctly with SonarQube 5.1 as it is called in full analysis without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior. This plugin does not work for incremental analysis for now. But maybe soon. See http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonarqube-and-Build-Breaker-Plugin-td5034703.html